# GAE getaddrinfo error on urlopen()

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building a simple application using GAE that fetches an URL and does some processing using urllib2 as stated in the documentation.

```
import webapp2
import urllib2

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = "http://www.google.com/"
        try:
            result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            self.response.out.write(result)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            handleError(e)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/", Handler)], debug = True)
```

Tried the same with urlfetch, but I keep getting the same error.

If I do the call to urlopen() with an IP address, it works fine.

I thought it could be a DNS issue, but calling `urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")` from the interpreter resolved correctly. Also, I can browse and ping without issues.

Asked some friends to try this code for me on their environment and the result was the same.

The deployed application running this same code works just fine.

I'm wondering if this could be a problem with my ISP, since all 3 tries were done from different places same ISP.

And no, I'm not going through proxy, at least not one I configured or one I can see.

Here's the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\test\main.py", line 8, in get
    result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\httplib.py", line 507, in getresponse
    'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e)
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://www.google.com/ Error: [Errno 10106] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me after I fix the code as follows:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Please check the setting of your DNS resolver, your security software, or http proxy configuration.

And, please don't keep creating similar new questions one after another.